# Store multiple secrets in Keyvault with one Azure Cli command

Tags: bash, azure-resource-manager, azure-cli

Sorry, Noobie here. Perhaps it is a very easy and obvious answer but I am trying to store an extensive list of keyvault secrets and am looking for an easy-ish way to do it compared with entering each one at a time. I figure using the CLI would be a quicker way to get this done than the Azure Resource Manager interface.

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this will actually help anyone because its so basic but I ended up creating a for loop script in bash that takes the input files as variables and dynamically creates the keyvault and populates said keyvault with the values based on the values.txt name.

running:

```
bash keyvault_creator.sh key.txt vault1.txt
```

runs:

```
#!/bin/bash

key=$1
value=$2

az keyvault create --location <location> --name "${value%.*}" --resource-group <ResourceGroupName>

paste $key $value | while read if of; do
  echo "$if" "$of"
  az keyvault secret set --vault-name "${value%.*}" --name "$if" --value "$of"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "ARM Interface" you mean a template, there is a template already written for this case: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/quickstarts/microsoft.keyvault/key-vault-secret-create

Comment: Apologies. ARM is Azure Resource Manager. Maybe a bit of an esoteric reference from within my organization. I have edited the original question.

Comment: Sorry - I'm with you on the ARM part - but the ARM "interface" is a REST API, I assume you didn't want to make [authenticated] REST calls directly but looking for help in orchestration.  The template sample will do that - PS/CLI have options too, the practice to keep in mind is making sure you have reusable code.

Comment: I mostly meant the web-GUI that goes along with ARM as it involves going through multiple pages just to set up each KeyVault, quite the chore. Solved the issue by writing bash script loop. I didn't quite firgure out the template use, but thank you for highlighting that. I will have to look into how to correctly implement those as I am sure they will be very useful in the future!